# Ireport designer for jasper reports with many columns

Tags: jasper-reports, width, ireport

I have a requirement where I have 20 columns in a report and would like to design one in ireport designer. It is not possible to stretch the width of the column header band in the ireport designer. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Is your column header static text?

Comment: You can select text and then right click->size-> Align parent.
If that doesn't work can you please post detail on how it appearing and how you expect?

Comment: I am trying to achieve horizontal scrolling in the report in order to fit all columns. I am not trying to increase the width of a single column header

Comment: If you have selected A4 page, you cann't do that. you have to select landscape or custom page format and specify the width and height you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the report right click-> page format, 
Select format as Custom
Give desired height and width in inches, select Landscape for page orientation.

Hope this helps!